# Image Hosting site: Django vs Pyramid

Tags: python, django, pylons, pyramid

I am the owner of an image hosting website.  I have been learning python for the past month as I plan to rebuild my website from PHP into Python as it is growing and I have found that Python will be extremely more efficient for my needs.

I have been doing research on the two most popular web frameworks for Python, Django and Pyramid.  From what I have gathered from reading various sources Pyramid appears to be a lower level framework giving it more speed and more flexibility.  While on the other hand Django is good for higher level websites that do not need a ridiculous amount of work put into them, and it's faster to set up.

I am leaning towards Pyramid since my website will probably grow to a large size in time and it will need to be as efficient as it could possibly be.  It would be awesome if I could get some more facts on the differences between these two frameworks and which one would better suit my needs of a large image hosting company.

Thanks :)

Comment: You should also consider [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Comment: [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/) is a mature and stable framework too.